# How to enable crashlytics for app which is having product flavors?

Tags: android, crashlytics

i want to enable crashlytis to perticular product flavor. i have integrated based on below docs. i can able to integrate in other sample app which does not have any flovour , it worked as expected. but in my project not working.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=2&platform=android#android]

after implemented the code then run it still showing 'Build and run your app' in firebase console. Please help. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @JeelVankhede firebase

Comment: Try this way `flavorImplementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'` and replace **flavor** with your **specific flavor**, do also for `flavorImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede i have done like this      southafricaImplementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1' but no use

Comment: Yes, it will work. Now run your app with that flavor and check on firebase console. *(Also look for log about crashlytics SDK initializatoin in logcat area in Android Studio)*

Comment: you have to run each build for flavor. change your build in Build Variants and run

Comment: @RajasekaranM i am running in required flavour only

Comment: @JeelVankhede still showing in console as Build and run your app.

Comment: Are you having **different applicationIds** for flavor specific build?

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes i have different applicationids

Comment: @JeelVankhede if we have applicationId in flavour do we need to follow different approach for crashlytics integration

Comment: No, you just use that **applicationId** to create your App on console and then integrate any respective service you want to consume in firebase *(Just don't forget to add particular **google-services.json** to your flavor directory)*.

Comment: Let me know if you need step by step solution.

Comment: @JeelVankhede thanks for your times. I got now. The reason is i have already fabric code inside project. i removed fabric code then working fine. Thanks again hero.

Comment: Happy to help :)